# Springboot SOAP service unmarshalling Issue with the response from WebServiceTemplate

Tags: web-services, spring-boot, soap

I am really bugged with an unmarshalling issue with the response from the SOAP service. I am using springboot application and WebServiceTemplate for calling an existing SOAP service. I am using below code to set up beans for marshalling and webservicetemplate. Any help is highly appreciated.

On calling `webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(request);` I am expecting `TravelResponse object` but it is giving me `JAXBElement<TravelResponse> object` as response. I need help to understand
1) why is it giving above response instead of `TravelResponse`
2) How to convert to `TravelResponse`

Code snippet below:

```
  @Bean
  Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
   jaxb2Marshaller.setContextPath("com.cater.trip.simple_api.trip.v1");
    return jaxb2Marshaller;
  }

  @Bean
  public WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate() throws Exception {
    WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();
    webServiceTemplate.setMessageFactory(getMessageFactory());
    webServiceTemplate.setMarshaller(jaxb2Marshaller());
    webServiceTemplate.setUnmarshaller(jaxb2Marshaller());
    webServiceTemplate.setDefaultUri(defaultUri);
    webServiceTemplate.setMessageSender(getMessageSender());
    return webServiceTemplate;
  }

  @Bean
  public SaajSoapMessageFactory getMessageFactory() {
      return new SaajSoapMessageFactory();
  }

  @Bean
  public HttpComponentsMessageSender getMessageSender() {         
      return new HttpComponentsMessageSender();
  }


 @Override
 public Object getData( ) {
    ObjectFactory clientFac = new ObjectFactory();
    TravelRequest request = populateRequest(clientFac);     
    TravelResponse res = (TravelResponse) webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(request);
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Spring's [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/client/core/WebServiceTemplate.html#marshalSendAndReceive(java.lang.Object)), `WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(Object requestPayload)`

> Sends a web service message that contains the given payload, marshalled by the configured Marshaller. **Returns the unmarshalled payload of the response message**, if any.
>   This will only work with a default uri specified!

So, you can do this to return the expected response.

```
JAXBElement<TravelResponse> res = (JAXBElement<TravelResponse>) webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(request);
return res.getValue();
```

Comment: Link to the doc please!

Answer (score 1):

Try JaxbIntrospector.getValue to get the actual response from JAXB element.

TravelResponse response = JaxbIntrospector.getValue(jaxbElement);